# I get weird <<...>> symbols in my output — what does it mean?

Tags: output-formatting

After I input the following:

```
data = Table[{3 + i + RandomReal[{-3, 7}], 
i + RandomReal[{-2, 5}]}, {i, 1, 20}];

model = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

I got something weird:

```
(*   FittedModel[-1.65238+<<19>>x]     *)
```

Does anyone know what `<<19>>x` means?

Comment: Try `model[x]` ;-)

Comment: I followed the tutorial precisely but the tutorial displayed the result that is understandable:
FittedModel[-1.65238+0.694915x]

How can I tweak the preference to get the same result?

Comment: it does for me (http://i.stack.imgur.com/eLOqb.png); please try from a new session?

Comment: @chris Perhaps something with a precision setting. `data = SetPrecision[
   Table[{3 + i + RandomReal[{-3, 7}], i + RandomReal[{-2, 5}]}, {i, 
     1, 20}], 200];` gets a similar result.

Answer (score 14):

`<<19>>` or `Skeleton[19]` means that some output (here 19 elements) is omitted. See the [ShortAndShallowOutput](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ShortAndShallowOutput.html) tutorial in the Documentation Center for more information.

Comment: How can I tweak the input to get something understandable?

Comment: @LeiChen It is important to realize that the output that you see is only a symbolical representation of the actual output. What you get returned is an *object* which knows several methods as Chris showed. How the object is depicted on your screen is totally irrelevant. It could have been a pink elephant, that doesn't matter, it's only decoration. If you're after the fit itself you can use `model["BestFit"]`

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`LinearModelFit` returns a full statistical information set.

For instance

```
   model[x]
```

would return

```
   (* 0.778634 x+1.13751  *)
```

or

```
   model["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More generally, try

```
   model /@ model["Properties"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think the question really was: _"Does anyone know what <<19>>x means"_ :)

Comment: @rm-rf probably, but if the OP is a real beginner he/she might be after understanding Mathematica's cryptic answer ;-)

Comment: Oh, I certainly agree (and going by their comment under ssch's answer, they're clueless). I thought I'd just point out, just in case you hadn't seen it :)

Comment: `<< +1 >>`  $\phantom{}$