# Finding the right DeleteCases pattern for <<199>>

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a list in *Mathematica* with several items like <<199>> and <<104>>, I would like to get rid of them using `DeleteCases`, but none of the patterns I have tried so far has worked.

Comment: `_Skeleton -> Sequence[]` (related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15188/5)

Comment: `<<199>>` typically indicates that 199 items are not *displayed* in the output, however, those items are still part of the list.  Are you certain that this is not the case in your application?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are dealing with something like this:

```
x1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, Range[0, 10, 1/3], 5, Sequence @@ Range[6, 99]};

x2 = Shallow[x1]
```

> ```
> {1,2,3,4,{0,1/3,2/3,1,4/3,5/3,2,7/3,8/3,3,<<21>>},5,6,7,8,9,<<90>>}
> ```

You may not have an explicit [`Shallow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Shallow.html) or [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Short.html) in your code; rather it may be applied automatically as part of a formatting function.

It is important to understand that this appearance of [`Skeleton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Skeleton.html) is typically *only* a matter of formatting; underlying that display form is a complete expression.

Perhaps you only want to see the entire expression (see [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputForm.html)) but since you are seeking to use `DeleteCases` I assume you wish to work with this display form itself.  How you do that will depend on the origin of the expression.  In my example above `Shallow` does not actually change the expression; it remains as an invisible head that is not displayed in the output, but rather changes how the output is displayed.  (This is similar to other formatting wrappers such as [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html).)  To operate on the display form one must actually convert the expression into Box form, as explained here: [Graphics in Notebook Different from Graphics Expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45808/graphics-in-notebook-different-from-graphics-expression/45813#45813)  Further, there appears to be a bug in parsing the Box form `RowBox[{"\[LeftSkeleton]", "21", "\[RightSkeleton]"}]` therefore one cannot directly use `ToExpression` which would simplify this operation.  However one can still use patterns that operate on the Box form expression itself:

```
Replace[
  ToBoxes[x2],
  h_[x___, ",", RowBox[{"\[LeftSkeleton]", _, "\[RightSkeleton]"}]] :> h[x],
  {0, -1}
] // ToExpression
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 4/3, 5/3, 2, 7/3, 8/3, 3}, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
> ```

Another approach would be to mimic the behavior of `Shallow` and circumvent it.  For example:

```
Replace[
 x1,
 a_ /; Length[a] > 10 :> Take[a, 10],
 {0, -1}
]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 4/3, 5/3, 2, 7/3, 8/3, 3}, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
> ```

I'll wait for a better description of the problem you actually face before taking this further.