# What's the meaning of <<19>> in the result

Tags: output

Try the following:

```
Ty1 = {11, 13, 19, 22, 27, 30, 41};
Tm1 = {0.4125, 0.42, 0.4933, 0.525, 0.539, 0.575, 0.52};
Tx2 = {20, 18, 35, 37, 38, 44, 57};
Tm2 = {0.5625, 0.47, 0.58, 0.59, 0.57, 0.6, 0.58};
Tx3 = {9, 12, 19, 21, 24, 27, 32};
Tm3 = {1.044, 1.234, 0.874, 0.811, 0.82, 0.708, 0.828};
data = Table[{Tx2[[i]], Tm1[[i]], Tx2[[i]], Tm2[[i]], Tx3[[i]], 
    Tm3[[i]], Ty1[[i]]}, {i, 7}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  k1*x2*m1^a + k2*x2*m2^b + k3*x3*m3^c + d, {k1, k2, k3, a, b, c, 
   d}, {x1, m1, x2, m2, x3, m3}, MaxIterations -> Infinity]
```

As output, you will get something like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is the meaning of `<<18>>` or `<<19>>`,and how to handle it?

Comment: See [Skeleton](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skeleton.html)

Comment: this happens when you have large (long) output, and M shortens it. It is like etc....

Comment: This question was already asked [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15189/187), but unfortunately you won't find it when searching for `<<` or `<<...>>`. So unless you know already that it is called `Skeleton` the available answer is unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<<..>>` notation in the output is called [`Skeleton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skeleton.html) and you don't have to handle it in any way, because the true expression is still there. *Mathematica* decided that the output would be too long for you to read and shortened it in a meaningful way.

The number that is used, like `<<19>>` tells you that there are 19 expressions hidden in this place. You can easily try this yourself, because `Short` or `Shallow` will produce them too:

```
Range[100]//Shallow
(* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,<<90>>} *)
```

As you see, *Mathematica* hides 90 elements from the list. Nevertheless, you can still work with your computed result

```
Total[%]
(* 5050 *)
```

Comment: Now the question is coming, in fact I want to konw the exact number hidden in the skeleton. However, I can't find any button like "show less " or "show more" around the output box, so what's the matter. If I can't get the exact result ,  it's still failed to me .

Comment: @user27564 What you probably want is simply `nlm["BestFit"]`, where `nlm` is the result of your computation. Look at the documentation of [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html?q=NonlinearModelFit) under Details.

Comment: Yes ,you got it ,thank you.