# Remove <<1>> from a long result

Tags: output

There may be already similar questions posted but since I am not still sure, let me ask the following question.

Is there any way to remove <<1>>'s from a very very lengthy output, so that the result becomes completely detailed? I would like to copy the very very long result as a text but <<1>>'s prevent me from doing that. Even worse, the buttons "show more" and "show all" do not appear below the output...What could I do?

P.S. I saved the data using DumpSave.

Comment: If the `<<1>>` was generated in a different session, I think the data is lost and cannot be recovered.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [I get weird <<…>> symbols in my output — what does it mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15188/5). I think you can strip them out by doing `/. _Skeleton :> Sequence[]` or `/. _Skeleton :> Nothing` (v10+) on the output.